# getStableInsetTop() always returning 0?

Tags: android, android-layout, windowinsets

I want to get the stable System UI insets. To get the System UI(Nav Bar and Status Bar) Height and Width from it.

**Problem:** I have used the `getSystemWindowInsetTop()` method of windowInsets class but it becomes zero when screen goes to immersive mode and System UI(Nav Bar and Status Bar) hides. But I want the Stable Insets and that's why I'm trying to use `getStableInsetTop()` method and it always returns 0.

**Code:**

```
binding.lytParent.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener((view, windowInsets) -> {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                        , windowInsets.getStableInsetTop()
                );
                binding.vTopMargin.setLayoutParams(params);
});
```

**Note:** I've added the `fitSystemWindows="true"` property in my parent layout in XML. `getSystemWindowInsetTop()` is working just fine and returning the Inset value but the problem is it's value changes with the Visibility of System UI(Nav Bar and Status Bar).